# MD RAID 6 with XFS Periodic Kernel Panic -- Possible Kernel Bug?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, kernel, mdadm

This now appears to be a bug with the combination of MD and XFS after finding similar kernel panic reports elsewhere. A bug report with Ubuntu has been filed here ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1929591 ) but there's been no response on that so I'll probably just give up and move on at this point -- Back up all my data, format the drives, and replace it with a ZFS array, completely ditching MD and XFS.

**Update 1/14/21 and 6/16/21 below.  Original post:**

I recently upgraded my NAS server from an old i7-2600K to a Ryzen 3700X. Both systems use software MD RAID 6 on 7 4TB HDDs, running Ubuntu 20.04. The MD RAID was transferred as-is to a fresh Ubuntu install. However, I am having an issue where this new build is periodically rebooting, approximately every 2-4 days.

I had the exact same issue on my new VM server I built at the same time (using a 5950X and running Proxmox), but that was fixed with disabling C-States in BIOS and adding `processor.max_cstate=5 rcu_nocbs=0-31` to the kernel args -- it currently has an uptime of 20 days which I am thrilled about. Doing the same thing on this machine did **not** fix the issue however.

I was not able to ever catch the kernel panic text until I setup a serial console server on a Raspberry Pi. It appears to be a recursive kernel panic which fills up any crash logs, which explains why my attempts at setting up `kdump` / `linux-crashdump` were never successful and always hard-locked with an out-of-memory error.

The kernel panic appears to be a bug in the MD driver of Linux. But I have no idea why it wasn't occurring on the same software on my old Intel hardware.

I have tried 2 different sets of RAM (and memtest86 reports both sets are OK), and many BIOS versions -- makes no difference. I originally was using Ubuntu 20.04 because I always use LTS, but decided to reinstall with Ubuntu 20.10 for a slightly newer kernel version (5.8) to see if that fixed it -- also same error.

Specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
- Mobo: ASRock X570 Pro4 ATX

  - Various BIOS versions attempted, inc. latest 3.60 down to 2.20
- RAM: GSkill Ripjaws V 32 GB DDR4-3200 F4-3200C16D-32G

  - Also used older set of Mushkin Enhanced Blackline 32GB DDR4-2400
- GPU: Zotac Geforce GTX 1650 OC SFF
- SSD: Inland Premium 1TB M.2
- HDD: 7x Western Digital Red (Plus) 4TB WD40EFRX

Running on this machine is Docker, including Plex, which is using the Nvidia Docker extensions with the proprietary 450.80 driver for hardware encoding (NVENC). I don't think the Nvidia driver is affecting this?

Some info:

```
$ lsb_release -ds
Ubuntu 20.10
$ uname -a
Linux babylon 5.8.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 09:14:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.8.0-33-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 processor.max_cstate=1 rcu_nocbs=0-15
$
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid6 sdc[7] sda[1] sdb[2] sde[3] sdd[4] sdg[6] sdf[5]
      19534435840 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/7] [UUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 4/30 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
$
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Jul  7 18:47:41 2018
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 19534435840 (18629.49 GiB 20003.26 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906887168 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
      Raid Devices : 7
     Total Devices : 7
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Tue Jan  5 22:26:49 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 7
   Working Devices : 7
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : america:0
              UUID : 279552e4:7db4a375:40a2a9bd:53f3c643
            Events : 34528

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       7       8       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
       1       8        0        1      active sync   /dev/sda
       2       8       16        2      active sync   /dev/sdb
       3       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
       4       8       48        4      active sync   /dev/sdd
       5       8       80        5      active sync   /dev/sdf
       6       8       96        6      active sync   /dev/sdg
$
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Jan  5 22:28:23 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 50%   33C    P0    N/A /  75W |      0MiB /  3911MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Serial Console Log at point of panic:

```
[161342.301305] BUG: stack guard page was hit at 00000000fc60f228 (stack is 00000000875efe77..000000003f38a379)
[161342.301306] kernel stack overflow (double-fault): 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
[161342.301306] CPU: 10 PID: 465 Comm: md0_raid6 Tainted: P           OE     5.8.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu
[161342.301307] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./X570 Pro4, BIOS P3.60 12/01/2020
[161342.301307] RIP: 0010:slab_free_freelist_hook+0x35/0x120
[161342.301308] Code: 89 d5 41 54 49 89 f4 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 08 48 8b 02 4c 8b 36 48 c7 06 00 00 00 00 48 c7 02 00 00 00 00 48 85 c0 49 0f 44 c6 <48> 89 45 d0 eb 06 4c 3b 7d d0 74 5d 8b 53 20 4d 89 f7 49 8d 34 16
[161342.301308] RSP: 0018:ffffa86b00c6fff8 EFLAGS: 00010246
[161342.301309] RAX: ffff98edc21cac40 RBX: ffff98ef0b407800 RCX: 0000000000000001
[161342.301310] RDX: ffffa86b00c70040 RSI: ffffa86b00c70038 RDI: ffff98ef0b407800
[161342.301310] RBP: ffffa86b00c70028 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: ffffffff85854500
[161342.301311] R10: ffff98edc21ca100 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffa86b00c70038
[161342.301311] R13: ffffa86b00c70040 R14: ffff98edc21cac40 R15: ffff98e9b53d74d8
[161342.301311] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff98ef0ec80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[161342.301312] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[161342.301312] CR2: ffffa86b00c6ffe8 CR3: 00000007fa766000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
[161342.301312] Call Trace:
[161342.301313]  ? mempool_kfree+0xe/0x10
[161342.301313]  ? kfree+0xb8/0x220
[161342.301313]  ? mempool_kfree+0xe/0x10
[161342.301313]  ? mempool_free+0x2f/0x80
[161342.301314]  ? md_end_io+0x4b/0x70
[161342.301314]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[161342.301314]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[161342.301315]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[161342.301315]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[161342.301315]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[161342.301315]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[161342.301316]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[161342.301316]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[161342.301316]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[161342.301316]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[161342.301317]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[161342.301317]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[161342.301317]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[161342.301317]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
...
[161342.301379]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[161342.301379]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[161342.301380]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[161342.301380]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[161342.301380]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[161342.301380]  ? bio_ch
[161342.301381] Lost 296 message(s)!
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.8.0-33-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-036) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.35.1) #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 09:14:40 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.8.0-33.36-generic 5.8.17)
```

I can reproduce this exact same kernel panic with `RIP: 0010:slab_free_freelist_hook+0x35/0x120` every time it reboots now. They all look exactly the same.

I'm at a loss as what to do at this point. I have a replacement motherboard coming (a Gigabyte B550M Aorus Pro) along with a LSI 9211-8i that I will instead connect the HDDs to. Maybe that will fix it? Is there something else in software/BIOS that I can do?

**UPDATE 1/14/2021:**

I swapped out the ASRock X570 Pro4 motherboard for the Gigabyte B550M Aorus Pro, as well as moving all the HDDs to an LSI 9211-8ik PCIe card. However, after some promising looking uptime, another similar kernel panic :(

```
[406005.583315] BUG: stack guard page was hit at 000000007cbff150 (stack is 000000003b7072a2..00000000dac5ed08)
[406005.583315] kernel stack overflow (double-fault): 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
[406005.583315] CPU: 15 PID: 514 Comm: md0_raid6 Tainted: P           OE     5.8.0-36-generic #40-Ubuntu
[406005.583316] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B550M AORUS PRO/B550M AORUS PRO, BIOS F1 05/19/2020
[406005.583316] RIP: 0010:slab_free_freelist_hook+0x35/0x120
[406005.583316] Code: 89 d5 41 54 49 89 f4 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 08 48 8b 02 4c 8b 36 48 c7 06 00 00 00 00 48 c7 02 00 00 00 00 48 85 c0 49 0f 44 c6 <48> 89 45 d0 eb 06 4c 3b 7d d0 74 5d 8b 53 20 4d 89 f7 49 8d 34 16
[406005.583316] RSP: 0018:ffffa620c06e3ff8 EFLAGS: 00010246
[406005.583317] RAX: ffff9aaf36f54720 RBX: ffff9ab34b407800 RCX: 0000000000000001
[406005.583317] RDX: ffffa620c06e4040 RSI: ffffa620c06e4038 RDI: ffff9ab34b407800
[406005.583317] RBP: ffffa620c06e4028 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: ffffffffb9c54500
[406005.583318] R10: ffff9aaf36f54fe0 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffa620c06e4038
[406005.583318] R13: ffffa620c06e4040 R14: ffff9aaf36f54720 R15: ffff9ab2925cbd10
[406005.583318] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9ab34edc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[406005.583318] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[406005.583318] CR2: ffffa620c06e3fe8 CR3: 00000005d52ac000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
[406005.583319] Call Trace:
[406005.583319]  ? mempool_kfree+0xe/0x10
[406005.583319]  ? kfree+0xb8/0x220
[406005.583319]  ? mempool_kfree+0xe/0x10
[406005.583319]  ? mempool_free+0x2f/0x80
[406005.583319]  ? md_end_io+0x4b/0x70
[406005.583319]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 6/16/2021:**

So yeah this is totally still happening. Another serial console capture:

```
babylon login: [1457468.880947] BUG: stack guard page was hit at 000000007aef1a4a (stack is 00000000af9c61cd..000000007ccda653)
[1457468.880948] kernel stack overflow (double-fault): 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
[1457468.880948] CPU: 3 PID: 512 Comm: md0_raid6 Tainted: P           OE     5.8.0-53-generic #60-Ubuntu
[1457468.880949] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B550M AORUS PRO/B550M AORUS PRO, BIOS F13h 04/23/2021
[1457468.880949] RIP: 0010:slab_free_freelist_hook+0x35/0x120
[1457468.880950] Code: 89 d5 41 54 49 89 f4 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 08 48 8b 02 4c 8b 36 48 c7 06 00 00 00 00 48 c7 02 00 00 00 00 48 85 c0 49 0f 44 c6 <48> 89 45 d0 eb 06 4c 3b 7d d0 74 5d 8b 53 20 4d 89 f7 49 8d 34 16
[1457468.880951] RSP: 0018:ffffbcda805efff8 EFLAGS: 00010246
[1457468.880952] RAX: ffff9bfb8ccc42a0 RBX: ffff9bfcdb407800 RCX: 0000000000000001
[1457468.880952] RDX: ffffbcda805f0040 RSI: ffffbcda805f0038 RDI: ffff9bfcdb407800
[1457468.880953] RBP: ffffbcda805f0028 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: ffffffff90841600
[1457468.880953] R10: ffff9bfb8ccc4f40 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffbcda805f0038
[1457468.880953] R13: ffffbcda805f0040 R14: ffff9bfb8ccc42a0 R15: ffff9bf766967940
[1457468.880954] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9bfcdeac0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[1457468.880954] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[1457468.880955] CR2: ffffbcda805effe8 CR3: 00000003a65ee000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
[1457468.880955] Call Trace:
[1457468.880955]  ? mempool_kfree+0xe/0x10
[1457468.880956]  ? kfree+0xb8/0x220
[1457468.880956]  ? mempool_kfree+0xe/0x10
[1457468.880956]  ? mempool_free+0x2f/0x80
[1457468.880956]  ? md_end_io+0x4b/0x70
[1457468.880957]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880957]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880957]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880958]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880958]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880958]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880959]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880959]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880959]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880959]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880960]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880960]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880960]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880960]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880961]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880961]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880961]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880962]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880962]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880962]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880962]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880963]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880963]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880963]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880963]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880964]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880964]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880964]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880965]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880965]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880965]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880965]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880966]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880966]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880966]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880966]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880967]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880967]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880967]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880968]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880968]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880968]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880968]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880969]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880969]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880969]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880969]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880970]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880970]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880970]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880971]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880971]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880971]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880971]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880972]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880972]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880972]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880972]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880973]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880973]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880973]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880973]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880974]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880974]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880974]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880975]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880975]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880975]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880975]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880976]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880976]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880976]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880976]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880977]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880977]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880977]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880978]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880978]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880978]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880978]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880979]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880979]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880979]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880979]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880980]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880980]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880980]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880981]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880981]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880981]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880981]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880982]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880982]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880982]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880982]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880983]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880983]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880983]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880984]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880984]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880984]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880984]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880985]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880985]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880985]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880985]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880986]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880986]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880986]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880987]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880987]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880987]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880987]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880988]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880988]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880988]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880988]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880989]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880989]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880989]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880989]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880990]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880990]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880990]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880991]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880991]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880991]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880991]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880992]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880992]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880992]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880992]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880993]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880993]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880993]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880994]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880994]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880994]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880994]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880995]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880995]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880995]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880995]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880996]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880996]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880996]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880997]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880997]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880997]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880997]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880998]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880998]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880998]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880998]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.880999]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.880999]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.880999]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881000]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881000]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881000]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881000]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881001]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881001]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881001]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881001]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881002]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881002]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881002]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881003]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881003]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881003]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881003]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881004]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881004]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881004]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881004]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881005]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881005]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881005]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881006]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881006]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881006]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881006]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881007]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881007]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881007]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881007]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881008]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881008]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881008]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881009]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881009]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881009]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881009]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881010]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881010]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881010]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881010]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881011]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881011]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881011]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881011]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881012]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881012]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881012]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881013]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881013]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881013]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881013]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881014]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881014]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881014]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881014]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881015]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881015]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881015]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881016]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881016]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881016]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881016]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881017]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881017]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881017]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881017]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881018]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881018]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881018]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881019]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881019]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881019]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881019]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881020]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881020]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881020]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881020]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881021]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881021]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881021]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881022]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881022]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881022]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881022]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881023]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881023]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881023]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881023]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881024]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881024]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881024]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881025]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881025]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881025]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881025]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881026]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881026]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881026]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881026]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881027]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881027]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881027]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881028]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881028]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881028]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881028]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881029]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881029]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881029]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881029]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881030]  ? bio_chain_endio+0x2d/0x40
[1457468.881030]  ? md_end_io+0x5d/0x70
[1457468.881030]  ? bio_endio+0xe6/0x150
[1457468.881030]  ? bi
[1457468.881031] Lost 306 message(s)!
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.8.0-53-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-020) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.35.1) #60-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 07:46:32 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.8.0-53.60-generic 5.8.18)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.8.0-53-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 processor.max_cstate=5 rcu_nocbs=0-15
```

Comment: Added an update for panic/reboot on 1/14/21. I was convinced it was a driver/software issue with the SATA ports on the X570 chipset, so I figured moving to B550 and then not using any on-board SATA and adding the LSI SAS card would fix it. Sad day.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, and went through the exact same steps. Also tested the memory and had no success with kdump, and also tried both B550 and X570. Here's my serial console log in case that helps somehow: https://imgur.com/a/zeV4QK2

Comment: I just posted an Ubuntu bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1929591